# How to implement a loop that will add push all registers to the stack

Tags: assembly, 8051

I'm attempting to write a loop in 8051 Assembly, that will go through the all the registers in the four register banks (Memory locations: 0x00 - 0x1F) and push them through the stack.

I've attempted to write a loop that will increment value to point memory locations 0x00 - 0x1F, since I need to push all of them into the stack I then attempt to get that value, push it to the stack and then increment that value, at the same time decrementing the limit in the accumulator to eventually end the loop once it's gotten through all of the registers

```
MOV 50H, 0  ;This is our index
MOV A, #1FH ;Move the limit into Acc


LOOP:
    PUSH @50H   
    INC 50H
    DEC A
    JNZ LOOP
```

It doesn't seem I'm able to push using a direct reference to memory, and I'm not sure how to otherwise implement it. The code does not assemble.

**Edit**

I attempted to instead move into registers with this code:

```
LOOP:
   MOV R1, @R0
   INC R0
   DEC A
   JNZ LOOP
```

However, I am getting an error: `Unknown Label - @R0``

Comment: For indirection you can only use `@R0` or `@R1` but not for `PUSH` unfortunately. As such, I recommend you save R0 into a temporary variable then use that to iterate your block of memory moving each byte into another temporary which you can `PUSH`. Finally, figure out which register bank is active and copy your saved `R0` into the appropriate location on the stack.

Comment: I've added an edit to my post with the new code I tried @Jester however I'm still receiving an error: `Unknown Label - @r0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For indirection you can only use `@R0` or `@R1` but not for `PUSH` unfortunately. As such, I recommend you save `R0` into a temporary variable then use `R0` to iterate your block of memory moving each byte into another temporary which you can `PUSH`. Finally, figure out which register bank is active and copy your saved `R0` into the appropriate location on the stack. Something like this (have not tested beyond the fact that it assembles):

```
    mov B, R0
    mov R0, #0
loop:
    mov A, @R0
    push ACC
    inc R0
    cjne R0, #20h, loop
    ; figure out which register bank is in use from PSW
    ; and write B into the appropriate location for R0
    mov A, PSW
    anl A, #18h  ; this gives 00h, 08h, 10h, 18h
    add A, SP    ; end of save area
    ; clr C      ; not needed as the above addition should never produce carry
    subb A, #20h ; size of save area
    mov R0, A
    mov @R0, B
    mov R0, B    ; restore original R0 if needed
```